# Why Aung San Suu Kyi is silent on brutality on Muslim minority in Burma?

Tags: human-rights, myanmar

[Sung San Suu Kyi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aung_San_Suu_Kyi) is a state counsellor of Myanmar. There are [severe violation of human rights in Myanmar](https://www.cnbc.com/amp/2017/08/25/at-least-32-killed-in-myanmar-as-rohingya-insurgents-stage-major-attack.html).

Why Aung San Suu Kyi is not taking any steps to save Muslims there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Aung Saan Su Kyi is another Nobel Peace Prize winner who has marked some question marks over "Nobility" of Nobel Prize.

To show you a glimpse of Aung Saan Su Kyi's "impartiality" towards Muslims, she [lost her cool](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/aung-san-suu-kyi-reportedly-said-no-one-told-me-i-was-going-to-be-interviewed-by-a-muslim-after-a6951941.html) last year during an interview by a Muslim BBC presenter and reported to have said the following words off the record:

> No one told me I was going to be interviewed by a Muslim [1](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/aung-san-suu-kyi-reportedly-said-no-one-told-me-i-was-going-to-be-interviewed-by-a-muslim-after-a6951941.html)

Not only [her military is responsible](http://www.ohchr.org/Documents/Countries/MM/FlashReport3Feb2017.pdf) for this brutality but she also seems to downplay the reports of human rights violations by her army (Source: [Burmese Nobel Prize Winner Aung San Suu Kyi Has Turned Into an Apologist for Genocide Against Muslims](http://Burmese%20Nobel%20Prize%20Winner%20Aung%20San%20Suu%20Kyi%20Has%20Turned%20Into%20an%20Apologist%20for%20Genocide%20Against%20Muslims)) .

Check these excerpts from her official website titled "[Fake Rape](http://www.statecounsellor.gov.mm/en/node/551)":

> The Information Committee of the State Counsellor’s Office issued a press release concerning the rumours that some women were raped during the area clearance operations of security forces following the violent attacks in Maungtaw Township.
>
> According to the press release, No. 1 Border Guard Police Command
>   Centre (Kyikanpyin), Koetankauk Police Outpost and Ngakhuya Police
>   Outposts were attacked by violent attackers at dawn on 9th October.
>   Nine police officers were killed and a total of 51 assorted weapons
>   and ammunition were lost during the attacks. After the attacks,
>   military columns comprising government troops and the police conducted
>   area clearance operations in the area to recover lost weapons and
>   ammunition and to capture the violent attackers in accordance with the
>   law. However, terrorists fabricated stories with the use of social
>   media and the internet while foreign new agencies spread bad news that
>   was contrary to the ethics of the media by publishing one-sided
>   accusations.

So a short answer of your question, unfortunately, is: 1-) She is biased against Muslims 2-) Everyone from Aung Saan Su Kyi to UN (I personally feel this [UN Security Council today's meeting on North Korea](http://wjla.com/news/nation-world/un-diplomats-call-for-more-sanctions-against-north-korea) is a stagged drama to divert the attention away from Rohingyas)

P.S:

- [Ken Roth - HRW's Executive Officer](https://twitter.com/KenRoth/status/904260883924348929)

Comment: I am not so sure the birman military can be called "her" military, it still has a rather large political power on its own. Also, "a staged drama to divert attention from Rohingyas " is a bold claim to make. Your personnal feeling should wonder if anyone at the UN would be able to "stage" that kind of drama while secretly pulling strings, all of this to divert attention  (and fail at it).

Comment: Point 2 seems incomplete.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I agree and that'swhy I mentioned it as a sidenote as my "personal" feeling. Rest of facts are backed by the references.

Comment: @Talha not just unreferenced, but flat out ungrammatical.

Comment: Aung Saan Su Kyi, ok, there is more than enough there to support your theory, but why would the UN Security Council "stage a drama" to divert attention away from Rohingyas? Russia and China have indeed blocked at least one statement from UN (Rohingyas related) but that hardly constitutes the entire UN body.

Comment: Point 2 seems like conspiracy-mongering, actually, and makes no sense, from a motivations perspective.

Answer (score 3):

Suu Kyi has a  racist instinct against Muslims.

For example,

1. http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/aung-san-suu-kyi-reportedly-said-no-one-told-me-i-was-going-to-be-interviewed-by-a-muslim-after-a6951941.html
2. http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/aung-san-suu-kyi-rohinga-muslims-not-the-liberal-made-herself-out-a7920296.html
3. http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/world/myanmars-suu-kyi-uses-facebook-to-fuel-hatred-towards-rohingyas/news-story/1126185e54089e10c80065fc87b2ed10

Answer (score -2):

This was discussed on BBC Radio 4's Today program. Aung San Suu Kyi accepted a constitution in which the Military has a significant role and considerable power. She has no authority over the Military.

It appears that she feels that she must pander to her predominantly Buddhist supporters. She fears that if she were to criticize the Military, it would have no consequence on the ground, and she would lose support. Without a clear majority, she would be sidelined or ousted by the Generals.

Comment: If she had already said this statement then why every one is blaming her for the brutality and even British Foreign Secretary Boris Johnson warned her that the oppression of the minority was “besmirching” her country’s reputation

Comment: Unclear answer.

Comment: Being State Counselor, she is alpha and omega of the country and ok even if we go with your assumption that she has no authority over the military, then still what is the point of her office publishing articles like "Fake Rape" and words like "Noone told me I was going to be interviewed by a Muslim", etc.